# Make inner div show on bottom

Tags: css

I making a thumbnail and wish have a inner div to display some content inside a div. I wish the inner div is on the bottom not on top , any idea how to change it ? Thanks

```css
.img_container{
 height:150px;
 width:200px;
 cursor:pointer;
 border-radius:2px;
 background:#333
}
.img_container img{
 height:150px;
 width:200px;
 position:absolute;
 margin:0 auto; 
 z-index:-999999;
}
.cat_container{
 background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .5);
 color:#fff;
 padding:5px;
 clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail_container">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="img_container">
                <img src="" />
                <div class="cat_container">bottom</div>
            </div>         
 
        </div>         
            
   </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `.img_container` a `position:relative` and then position `.cat_container` at the bottom using `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`.

```
.img_container{
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#333;
    position:relative;
}
.cat_container{
    background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .5);
    color:#fff;
    clear:both;
    padding:5px 0;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/w3gq6f17/).

Answer (score 0):

You got the  90% of results use this css

```
 .img_container{
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#333;
    position: relative;
}

.img_container{
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:2px;
    background:#333;
  position: relative;
}

.img_container img{
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;  
    z-index:-999999;
}

.cat_container{
    background: rgba(25, 25, 25, .5);
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px 0px;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```